# When $f_x=f_y$, does that mean that all double partial derivative are the same?

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, partial-derivative

While working with some partial derivatives, I noticed that some functions' partial derivatives are the same (e.g. $f_x=f_y$). For example, both partial derivatives of $e^{2x+2y}$ are $2e^{2x+2y}$. When this occurs, you can apply the following logic:$$f_{xx}=(f_x)_x=(f_y)_x=f_{yx}=f_{xy}=(f_x)_y=(f_y)_y=f_{yy}$$This means that all the double partial derivatives are the same. I believe similar logic should apply for higher order partial derivatives. For example, $f_{xyyxxyxxx}=f_{yyxyyxxxy}$. This seems like a really powerful tool, but I wasn't tought it in Calc III, so I'm questioning if I made a mistake somewhere, and this isn't actually a valid technique.

Comment: I mean firstly, it should be defined right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your "technique" is right, but it is not a "really powerful tool" since it applies only to functions of the type $f(x,y)=g(x+y)$, $f_x=g'(x+y)⋅1$, $f_y=g'(x+y)⋅1$ so for example for $(x+y)^n$, $\sin(x+y)$, $\ln(x+y)$ etc. Once you see a function of this type you can use your rule, but most of the functions you have to deal with are not of this simple type.

Comment: Cool, maybe I'm over-estimating how often these functions show up, but it's good to now that the method checks out.

Comment: @SebastianNuxoll This is a specific case of an actually really powerful tool: solving linear partial differential equations (here $\partial_x f - \partial_y f = 0$).

Comment: @eyeballfrog Thanks, I think i found my next wikipedia rabbithole